# problem login geoexplorer - redirect IP

Tags: geoserver, javascript, web-mapping, geoexplorer, administration

I have problems when I want to log the administrative user through GeoExplorer when geoserver is running on a server with public ip but redirection to a private ip.

GeoExplorer takes too long to load and when it finally starts the login button does not appear in the interface. (in firedebug can be seen that there is no of cookies data).

If I access the GeoExplorer from the internal network, the login button load properly, GeoExplorer fast loading and allows me to make the user login.

The only open through public ip port is 80. Instead for access through the internal network are all open ports.

I am using: geoserver 2.4.0 , Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: `server with public ip but redirection to a private ip`?  Can you debug the issue with something like Firebug?

Comment: Oh yes! server with public ip but redirection to a private ip: the server with my geoserver this on a computer with a private IP. But access is required from the outside, then the network administrator assign a public ip. All requests to port 80 of ip public are redirected to port 80 server with private ip. Only requests to port 80 of ip public are available, since the other ports are filtered. I think the problem may be your firewall, you say?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it as follows.

The internal computer does not see itself due to network settings. The external server name was not resolved by the internal computer.

I modified the hosts file on the internal computer local ip assigning the name of the external computer, like this:

127.0.0.1 ...... nombre.noip.me

Where is the external or public name nombre.noip.me with which the direction of our geoserver is resolved:

http://nombre.noip.me:8080/geoserver

Sorry for my English.